# What does output mean

Tags: bitcoin-core

Will my bitcoin be there after syncronising  Am trying to sweep from my syncronising bitcoin core using my private key but its showing no output whats going on

Comment: can you post a screenshot/log output?

Comment: Okay i will but please before that let me explain better  my bitcoincore is syn and i have my bitcoin in it so from the videos i watched on youtube i went took the reciving address and paste in debuorg and i got a private key and i firstly i paste the private key on a sweep website and the new address i want to send it too and it saying no utxo for this addres and i also tried it on electrum is says no output needed to confirm the output thays what prompt my question is there anything i need to do thanks

Answer (score 1):

An **output** is the spending part of a transaction, that establishes ownership of the funds. **UTXO** is an unspent transaction output. UTXO to your address are counted toward your balance. When you want to send Bitcoin, a UTXO is needed as an **input** to the transaction.

It is likely that if your node is syncing from scratch it doesnt know about the UTXO related to your address, yet. If it hasn't processed the block that contains the UTXO, it might not know about it, so it doesn't know you have a balance.  If you use the Bitcoin core wallet, there is a wallet database that stores that data.

Comment: Yes i use bitcoin core wallet so what will i do not curse i trued to copy the address and paste it in blockchain to see and it says only 1 transaction and the balance is there , so what should i do now wait till it liaf the block or what curse i need my coin and and its still syn

Comment: Yeah it sounds like you might need to wait for it to finish syncing.

Comment: Will i meet my coin there if it finish syn and i want to ask the address i sent the bitcoin to i checked on. Blockchain  it show rhe monay i transferd to it and the balance it means the money is in the address right

Comment: Yes, you can also verify with a block explorer before it's done syncing.

Comment: What if my computer couldn't finish the syn how can i retrive my butcoin or have i lost it

Comment: If you have the private key you can use different wallet software that will let you import the private key, and then submit a transaction that way. You don't have to run a full node to make transactions.

Comment: And how will i do that

Comment: you will need to do your own research and select a wallet that you trust, this site isn't really for software recommendations.

Comment: Can i talk to you outside this place and can you explain better how i can use the private key on other if my computer could not finish the syn bitcoin co

Comment: There is a chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8089/mempool

Comment: I cant use it am new i dnt have up to 20 reputation ro use the chatroom

Comment: The blockchain should finish syncing, if it doesn't you can post another question.